# iOS Swift - prepareForSegue - indexPathForSelectedRow

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I was wondering if there is a way to use a different "indexPath" value as the key that is used in a segue...

The reason is, I've got JSON feed data that is not grouped and sorted:

```
{ "results":
[
 {
 "BusCat01": "Household",
 "CompanyDescription": "Household",
 "CompanyName": "Bed \u0026 Bath Store",
 "objectId": "Vq3lmoE0PA",
 },
 {
 "BusCat01": "Food",
 "CompanyDescription": "Hot Dogs",
 "CompanyName": "Wiener Schnitzl",
 "objectId": "xcCeuVoexD",
 },
 {
 "BusCat01": "Clothing",
 "CompanyDescription": "Clothing",
 "CompanyName": "Banana Republic",
 "objectId": "FGV8QuHmiw",
 }
]
}
```

I've consumed the JSON and then written my own grouping and sorting code. When I display the Grouped and Sorted data in a TableView the ordinals (row keys) don't correspond JSON keys. This corrupts the Master/Detail data. Basically I get the wrong Details for a given Master record in the table view. Example:

```
println("cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: \(indexPath)")
```

prints:

> cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
>
> cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}
>
> cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}
>
> cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}
>
> cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 1 - 0}
>
> cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 1 - 1}
>
> cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 2 - 0}
>
> cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 2 - 1}
>
> cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 3 - 0}

See the "path = ..." ???

Question: Is it possible to use my JSON "objectId" as the "indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row" value instead of the tableViews' section and row value in the "prepareForSegue"? (mouthful, I know...)

Here is the Grouping and Sorting:

```
func getData_VendorsByCategory() {
    clearData()
    if vendors.count > 0 {
        for object in vendors {
            let key = object.busCat01
            if vendsInCatDict.indexForKey(key!) != nil { // Add item to a pre-existing List that contains pre-existing Items
                vendsInCatDict[key!]?.append(object.companyName!)
                vendsArr.append(object.companyName!)
                vendsArr = sorted(vendsArr, descending)
            } else { // Create an array and add item to it
                vendsInCatDict[key!] = [object.companyName!]
                catsArr.append(key!)
                catsArr = sorted(catsArr, descending)
                vendsArr.append(object.companyName!)
                vendsArr = sorted(vendsArr, descending)
            }
        }
    }
}

func getData_VendorsByName() {
    clearData()
    if vendors.count > 0 {
        for object in vendors {
            let key = object.companyName as String?
            var index = advance(key!.startIndex, 1)
            var firstCharacter = key!.substringToIndex(index)

            if vendsInCatDict.indexForKey(firstCharacter) != nil { // Add item to a pre-existing List that contains pre-existing Items
                vendsInCatDict[firstCharacter]?.append(object.companyName!)
                vendsArr.append(object.companyName!)
                vendsArr = sorted(vendsArr, descending)
            } else { // Create an array and add item to it
                vendsInCatDict[firstCharacter] = [object.companyName!]
                catsArr.append(firstCharacter)
                catsArr = sorted(catsArr, descending)
                vendsArr.append(object.companyName!)
                vendsArr = sorted(vendsArr, descending)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear

Comment: Can you add your `UITableViewDataSource` methods to the question? Then we'll be able to see how your indexes are set up. These would be `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, `numberOfRowsInTableView` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @boidkan - That's the best I can do... It's very complex

Answer (score 1):

The `indexPath` indicates a location in the table view. If you used an array to build the table in your `UITableViewDataSource`, you can just use `indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row` and/or `indexPathForSelectedRow()?.section` as the index on this array.

EDIT: Based on your comment, you will need to reverse the steps you used to get the `nameSection`.

```
    let key = catsArr[indexPath.section]
    let nameSection = vendsInCatDict[key]!
    cell.textLabel?.text = nameSection[indexPath.row]
    return cell
```

So given the `indexPath` of a cell, you can retrieve the `key` and `nameSection` with the first two lines. Given those values, you'll need a function that can find an object in the original results array based on it's key/nameSection (reverse `getData_VendorsByCategory` and/or `getData_VendorsByName`). I'd suggest creating a lookup array or dictionary when doing your grouping and sorting.

For example, if you added something like:

```
// Top of class
var vendorMap : [String:AnyObject] = []

// In group/search
for object in vendors {
    let key = object.companyName as String?
    vendorMap[key!] = object
```

You can retrieve a vendor object like this:

```
let key = catsArr[indexPath.section]
let nameSection = vendsInCatDict[key]!
let vendor = vendorMap[nameSection[indexPath.row]]
```

Comment: I’m using a Singleton object in:

 viewDidLoad() {
vendors = LibraryAPI.sharedInstance.getVendors()
}

=== Then running “vendors” through my Grouping and Sorting algorithms (Array’s, Dicts) ===

getData_VendorsByCategory() {…}
getData_VendorsByName() {…}


=== Then marking it all up in the TableView delegates ===

tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
let key = catsArr[indexPath.section]
        let nameSection = vendsInCatDict[key]!
        cell.textLabel?.text = nameSection[indexPath.row]
return cell
}

Comment: @ Tom - "You will need to keep track of how the grouped and sorted data correspond to your original objects."   Yeah... I thought about that. It's just getting so "thick"... I was hoping there would be something more simple I was missing...

Comment: I've added a suggestion for how you might go about storing the object map. Might need a little tweaking as I've not tested it thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks Tom! I'll think that over